# download file to custom directory

Tags: android, download-manager

I am using the DownloadManager to download a file to my Android device. I can choose to download to the DCIM, Downloads, Picutures folder, etc using:

```
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file.jpg");
```

This works. But I can only choose a limit set of folders to download to. I want to download to the root of my sdcard using /sdcard/

I tried:

```
downloadRequest.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/file.jpg")));
```

But this renders the following exception:

> IllegalStateException: android invalid combination of destination: 4, path: /sdcard/file.jpg

How can I do this? I have all the required permissions set.

Comment: Have you tried without "file.jpg"?

Comment: @AgataSworowska same result...java.lang.IllegalStateException: invalid combination of destination: 4, path: /sdcard I get same error if I try a subdir of sdcard

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try like this.

```
downloadRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/folderName",file.jpg);
```

This will create a folder in you external storage root and place the file.jpg in it.

Comment: Does the setDestinationInExternalPublicDir works on Samsung devices? I tried on Galaxy S3 and it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by using

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir( "/APP_NAME/", FileNameGetter.getFileName(DATA..url) );
```

Comment: What is FileNameGetter in your example? Is that part of some library?

Comment: @bvanvelsen, its small method, which gets me the file name from url.

Comment: @kaibuki then your anser is incomplete please add that method also.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html), you should only use either of the following variants, using one of the available [`Environment.DIRECTORY_*`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) constants:

```
myRequest.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "my_sub_folder/my_file.txt");
```

where the directory type (i.e. the first parameter) may *not* be `null`, or

```
myRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(myContext, null, "my_sub_folder/my_file.txt");
// or
// myRequest.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(myContext, Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES, "my_sub_folder/my_picture.jpg");
```

where the directory type (i.e. the second parameter) *may* be `null`.

In any case, specifying a (sub)folder in the *last* parameter is optional.

Answer (score 0):

`Not one of standard directories: /folderName`. For `setDestinationInExtrnalPublicDir()` to work the given path must be one of the standard directories such as Music, Download etc...